# Nested select query in sql server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql

I am working on migration of my database from Oracle to Sql Server. 
I have a table definition as follows (in MS SQL Server 2012):

```
CREATE TABLE DEMO_TABLE(
ID BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
COLUMN_1 BIGINT NULL,
COLUMN_2 VARCHAR(256) DEFAULT NULL,
DATE_CREATED DATETIMEOFFSET DEFAULT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() NULL,
OPERATIONS NUMERIC(10,0) DEFAULT 0 NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_DEMO_TABLE PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

which works fine. 
Now, I have a select statement in Oracle as follows:

```
select * from (select 
            COLUMN_1,
            COLUMN_2,
            DATE_CREATED,
            OPERATIONS,
            SYSTIMESTAMP,
            row_number()
        over (order by date_created DESC) rn 
        from 
            DEMO_TABLE 
        where 
            COLUMN_1 = 3 AND 
            OPERATIONS IN 
            (1,2,3,4)
            AND COLUMN_2='sometext'
            AND DATE_CREATED <= SYSTIMESTAMP        
        ) where rn between 1 and 100 order by rn
```

I am facing problems in converting this select statement from  Oracle to SQL server.
This query works fine in Oracle, but gives the following error in SQL Server:

`Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.`

I can't figure out what is the problem here. Please help!

Comment: You have SQL Server in the question title but have Oracle, MySQL tagged?

Comment: @MurDeR Yes, because I thought may be there is some logical issue in the query, which is independent of the server I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from 
(select 
            COLUMN_1,
            COLUMN_2,
            DATE_CREATED,
            OPERATIONS,
            SYSTIMESTAMP,
            row_number()
        over (order by date_created DESC) rn 
        from 
            DEMO_TABLE 
        where 
            COLUMN_1 = 3 AND 
            OPERATIONS IN 
            (1,2,3,4)
            AND COLUMN_2='sometext'
            AND DATE_CREATED <= SYSTIMESTAMP        
        ) r
        where r.rn between 1 and 100 order by r.rn
```